# While adding the experience to profile experience get added multiple times

Tags: bug, profile-page

While adding the experience I accidentally added wrong date. Then after correcting the dates, I hit the save button, but it didn't get added, so I clicked a second time. Because of this, the experience got added that much time:

[image]

Comment: seems a bug. for now, you can delete extras and retain one. good luck.

Comment: I did it already.. I just inform for better development..